# Connect my Mysql RDS instance to my Heroku env

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, security, heroku, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect my MySql RDS instance to my Heroku environment securely, but I can't whitelist my ENV's ip address because (as I understand it) Heroku changes the ip address' at random.

Using the config vars with the DB credentials and connecting them with an ip of 0.0.0.0 in the security group works, but isn't a best practice security wise. What alternatives are available to me?

I've toyed with the idea of adding an ssl cert to my codebase, but this also doesn't seem like a very good idea.

Comment: For this setup, your main approach is a very strong password. (Heroku uses this approach for their own RDS-like Postgres offering.)

Comment: @ceejayoz Makes sense. What about the ip address' in the security group? Isn't that a concern security wise, or is there nothing I can do about that?

Comment: Nothing you can do. It's a concern, yes, and I wouldn't want to fight a PCI or HIPAA auditor over it. For less sensitive stuff, though, the strong random password is sufficient mitigation for most.